# How do I select last x% of rows from a query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to select, say, the last 1/x portion of  rows from a query, ordered in a certain way. How can I do this?

I've come up with something like

```
SELECT avg(smilies_count)
FROM posts AS p
WHERE time >= (???) -- I only want the last 25% of posts in this thread
GROUP BY thread_id; -- each thread can have more than 1 post, but I still only
                    -- want to consider the last 25% of posts in my average
```

but I'm not too sure what to put in the `???` that wouldn't result in an extremely gnarly expression.

**EDIT**

I've tried putting

```
SELECT min(p2.time)
FROM posts AS p2
WHERE p2.thread_id = p.thread_id
ORDER BY p2.time DESC
LIMIT count(*) / 4
```

in the `???`, but it only gave me

```
Error: misuse of aggregate function count()
```

Comment: you have a post_id column in posts table? and solution should be sqlite only?

Comment: @Dooh yes, I do have a post_id, and any solution should be fine as long as it works in SQLite too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you basically want 25% of last posts from every thread, and later operations are up to you.

If I am right, then this code should work for you (written for MS-SQL, should be portable to SQLite easily):

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
    post_id INT,
    thread_id INT
)

INSERT INTO posts(post_id, thread_id) VALUES (1, 1)
INSERT INTO posts(post_id, thread_id) VALUES (2, 2)
INSERT INTO posts(post_id, thread_id) VALUES (3, 2)
INSERT INTO posts(post_id, thread_id) VALUES (4, 3)
INSERT INTO posts(post_id, thread_id) VALUES (5, 3)
INSERT INTO posts(post_id, thread_id) VALUES (6, 3)
INSERT INTO posts(post_id, thread_id) VALUES (7, 3)
INSERT INTO posts(post_id, thread_id) VALUES (8, 3)
INSERT INTO posts(post_id, thread_id) VALUES (9, 3)
INSERT INTO posts(post_id, thread_id) VALUES (10, 3)
INSERT INTO posts(post_id, thread_id) VALUES (11, 3)

SELECT src.*
FROM (
    SELECT post_number = (
        SELECT 1 + COUNT(*)
        FROM posts pp 
        WHERE p.post_id > pp.post_id 
        AND p.thread_id = pp.thread_id
    ), 
    post_id,
    thread_id
    FROM posts p
) src
JOIN (
    SELECT thread_id, cnt = COUNT(*)
    FROM posts
    GROUP BY thread_id
) counts
ON src.thread_id = counts.thread_id
WHERE (CONVERT(FLOAT, src.post_number) / CONVERT(FLOAT, counts.cnt)) >= 0.75
```

Note that it's not performant query, mainly due to subquery that gets post_number. It could be written with OVER clause in much better way for DBMS that supports it.

Comment: Many thanks, finally got it working. I suppose SQL may not be the language best suited for this task, haha

Answer (score -1):

This's a version in case that you need last 25% of overall posts:

```
select
  avg(1.0 * smilies_count) avg_count,
from (select top 25% * from posts order by time desc) last_posts
```

And this's one more for last 25% of posts for every thread:

```
select
  avg(1.0 * smilies_count) avg_smilies
from (
  select
    thread_id, post_id, smilies_count,
    row_number() over (partition by thread_id order_by time desc) row_num
  from posts
) p
join (select thread_id, count(*) cnt from posts group by thread_id) c on
  p.thread_id = c.thread_id
where
  p.row_num < 0.25 * c.cnt
group by
  p.thread_id
```

Comment: I think you have missed the requirement to get last 25% posts for every thread, which is implicitly stated in the question ("group by thread id" from sample query)

Comment: @Dooh not sure that it implicitly follows from `group by` clause but ok :)

Comment: @pkuderov Would you explain what `last_post` is for?

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 there're last 25% of overall posts